# World Death rate data

Tags: data-science

I'd like to know  where I can find data about worldly deaths. I'd like to compare 2020 deaths with 2019 or other years and see what are the difference between then. Does anyone know where I can find a trustfull data about that?

Comment: This belongs on [Statistics StackExchange](https://www.stats.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a computer programming question.

Answer (score 1):

Kaggle is becoming the go-to source for all sorts of public data sets, including demographics.

Check out: https://www.kaggle.com/tags/mortality